# What are the steps to upgrade maven/grails from 1.2.0 to 1.2.1?

Tags: grails, maven

I have recently started a new project using the maven grails archetype - at the time, (a few weeks ago), Grails 1.2.0 was the most recent release. Now that there's a newer release, what are the steps to upgrade? I would assume that since Grails dependencies are defined in the POM, that the POM will need to be updated? Are there any instructions on doing this? Does the maven-grails-plugin handle this? Is this documented anywhere?

Appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://n4.nabble.com/Issues-after-upgrade-to-1-2-1-td1556099.html):

> The recommended way of upgrading grails is simply "grails upgrade" in the project dir when you have downloaded the new version of Grails and set up your paths etc...

Note that I've seen at least one person reporting problems with version 1.2.1 (and the Hibernate plugin), see [this thread](http://n4.nabble.com/maven-problem-after-upgrade-to-grails-1-2-1-td1459798.html). There is a workaround in the thread but maybe have a look at the Grails Jira first to see if there are any blocking issues with 1.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "upgrade" target in the maven grails
plugin, so I'm still looking for information on doing this upgrade with maven.